# how does google's inbox async calls works?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, gmail, google-inbox

by placing this small snippet in chrome's console can hook to any ajax call in a page:

```
(function(open) {
  XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async) {
    console.log('ajax call!'); //do things
    open.call(this, method, url, async);
  };
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open);
```

placing this in Gmail works but not in Google's new Inbox site.
if ajax call are not made in this page - what other way do they use to get async data?

Comment: Maybe a Websocket connection. You can check in Chrome dev-tools under network.

Comment: i see requests are made, but don't know how. any idea how to hook into them?

Comment: Something like this could work - http://jsfiddle.net/vnPbV/64/

Comment: You might also need to wrap the sockets `addEventListener` function, since message handlers can also be added like that.

Comment: You can verify very easily by going to the network tab that it is indeed making `XMLHttpRequest`s and can get chrome to "break on XHR" (in the sources tab), here's the relevant line: `A.send(t ? t : null)`.

Comment: If you check the part where they do " bu = function() {"  you can see that it indeed does use `XMLHttpRequest`s

Comment: Overriding `open` works just fine here, p.s. you should proxy with `return open.apply(this, arguments)`

Answer (score 1):

They might sending XHR requests from internal iframe/s so overriding XMLHttpRequest in the console won't work.